# Interface inheriting interface but not overriding methods

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I recently ran into an issue with a generic interface. I wanted to create a list of the interface, but that isn't that easy with the generic interface. I could create the list like this: `new List<IModelCreator<IDataCollection>>();` But I think that looks ugly.

So now I have 2 interfaces. One with a generic and one without. Here are the interfaces I use now:

```
public interface IModelCreator
{
  IDataCollection GetModelFromPath(string path); 
}

public interface IModelCreator<T>: IModelCreator where T : IDataCollection
{
  new T GetModelFromPath(string path);
}
```

`IModelCreator` is a class that turns a file path into a model and the `T` is the model it will get turned into. So I use this in my class now and I get this:

```
public abstract T GetModelFromPath(string path);

IDataCollection IModelCreator.GetModelFromPath(string path)
{
  return GetModelFromPath(path);
}
```

(I made it an abstract). But isn't there a way to make this just 1 method instead of 2 but with the same functionality?

I also tried with just the non-generic interface. I then have an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class DocumentConverterCreatorBase<T>: IModelCreator where T: IDataCollection
```

But then I wasn't able to use my generic `T` as a return type. And I have no idea why.

Comment: Hint: you should never have to put `new` before a member in a good design. It is a band-aid.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's the only thing I was kinda happy with. I could come up with that or the List variant I talked about in my post. I just hope I can get some answers here that will help me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
public class ModelList : List<IModelCreator<IDataCollection>> { }

//And then use it like this
ModelList  l = new ModelList();
```

Comment: That's a really clean way of doing it. I like thanks, thanks! Though isn't it weird to have an empty class? Or can we live with that because it's extending an abstract one?

Comment: I don't think so at all. It now allows you to add methods, helpers, or other things that assist in operation to the list. It's also a lot easier to remember when typing then "List<IModelCreator<IDataCollection>>".

Comment: An alternative approach that doesn't create a new type, but instead just uses an alias is: `using ModelList = List<IModelCreator<IDataCollection>>;`